# android: monitor x,y coordinates of the moving spot buttons during the animation

Tags: android, animation, coordinates

In my app there are 8 spots dropping from the top to the bottom, I would like how to add in the codes such that each spot can update its x, y coordinates so that when the basket below is suitably placed, it will record score +1.

## Code:

### Declaration

```
   // collections of spots (Buttons) and Animators 
   private final Queue<Button> spots = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Button>();
```

### adding spot in this way

```
   // adds a new spot at a random location and starts its animation
   public void addNewSpot()
   {
       int x = random.nextInt(viewWidth - SPOT_DIAMETER);
       int y = 0 - SPOT_DIAMETER;                      

       int x2 = x;
       int y2 = (viewHeight);

      // create new spot
      final Button spot = (Button) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.untouched, null);
      spots.add(spot);
```

### animate spot in this way:

```
spot.animate().x(x2).y(y2).scaleX(SCALE_X).scaleY(SCALE_Y).setDuration(animationTime).setListener
      (
            new AnimatorListenerAdapter() 
            {
               @Override
               public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation)
               {
                  animators.add(animation); // save for possible cancel
               } 

               public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
               {
                  animators.remove(animation); // animation done, remove

                  if (!gamePaused && spots.contains(spot)) // not touched
                  {
                     XX = (int) spot.getX();
                     YY = (int) spot.getY();

                      missedSpot(spot); // lose a life
                  } 
               } 
            } 
      );
```

## Question:

How to monitor the x,y coordinates of every spot, such that for example, the x is within the basket width and y is at the top of basket, the spot is treated as thown into the basket?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a direct solution on the above question.
Instead, I add a time counter such that when the millisecond hits for example, %3000 =0, it will invoke the Checking condition to check all the spots on the view. In this way, it works as if checking all the time.